What does the "-1" in GeoServer "Maximum number of granules to load" / "MaxAllowedTiles" mean?
I'm trying to set an ImageMosaic layer in GeoServer. The default value of the field Maximum number of granules to load is -1. Is it the same with the MaxAllowedTiles found in some examples in the net? In some docs I saw it been set to
2147483647, while others just say it should be "opportunely" set. So, what does it signify and, more important, how can I calculate an 'opportune' setting?

-1 is usually used to indicate no constraint (or as many as possible, hence the max int value you sometimes see). If you don't have a small server or a very large mosaic (millions of granules) you don't need to set this value. If you see degradation of performance on the server then set a sensible number based on how much memory you have divided by the size of a granules.

Thanks, Ian. One clarification, please: By "memory" you mean the total OS memory, the 'baseline' free OS memory or the xmx java heap setting (or something else)?

The java heap size
